# Javax Annotation Validation JUnit without Hibernate validator

Tags: java, junit, bean-validation

I have a jax-rs project that uses javax annotations (`@NotNull, @Pattern etc.`). I want to add unit tests for validating these annotations, but unfortunately cannot use the hibernate-validator (company maven repo does not have it) as suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41671471/3076069) answer. Is there any other way to validate the annotations using unit tests ?

Comment: You do not require hibernate validator specifically, but you do require at least some implementation of beanvalidator API. You can import any of them (use search), and they should work pretty much the same, except maybe some initial setup.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7470253/m-prokhorov - I have searched for an alternative to hibernate-validator and could not find one, hence the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apache's [Bval](http://bval.apache.org) provides a validator implementation that can serve as an alternative to hibernate-validator. Here's an [example](http://www.baeldung.com/apache-bval) for getting started on using Bval.