# When is validation used?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, annotations

I just wanted to write a test for a User class to check the validation. I'm wondering that nothing is validated as annotated.

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2, max = 255)
    private String username;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(length = 60)
    private String password;

    public User(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username.trim();
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying this:

```java
User user2 = new User("admin", "");
User user3 = new User("", "test");
User user4 = new User("", "");
```

And I assumed some exceptions but nothing.

- So is there a way to test these annotations?
- And when are those validations fired up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test validation annotations of a class using JUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069956/how-to-test-validation-annotations-of-a-class-using-junit).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So is there a way to test these annotations?

Yes, you need a [`javax.validation.Validator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Validator.html) instance to perform a validation:

```
// obtain a validator
ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
Validator validator = factory.getValidator();

// do a test
Set<ConstraintViolation<User>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(user2);
Assert.assertEquals(0, constraintViolations.size());
```

> And when are those validations fired up?

They might be fired up at different levels.

For example, Spring can integrate validation on the controllers layer (when a request come) with [`@javax.validation.Valid`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/Valid.html). Or you can put a validator to fire exceptions right before sending data to the database.